# Number of solutions to linear diophantine equations, with natural coefficients in a box

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, computational-complexity

Let c, k, d $ \in \mathbb{N} $, let **a**, **x** $ \in \mathbb{N}^k $ suppose for all i $ \leq $ k, $ x_i \leq d $, $ a_i \in \mathcal{O}(d2^i) $ and $ \sum{a_ix_i} = c $ my question is for the value of c that maximizes the number of solutions to this equation, what is a tight bound for the number of solutions to this equation for said c. I know that in the related problem of the number of solutions for a given c, when the $x_i's$ are unrestrained as c -> $ \infty $ the number of solutions is roughly $ \mathcal{O}(c^k) $.

However, my intuition tells me that constraining the $x_i$'s should reduce the maximal number of solutions to roughly $ \mathcal{O}(2^k) $ for any c, since the bounds for the $ x_i's $ guarantees zero solutions after a certain point, and the bound the $a_i's$ spreads the solution over a relatively wide range.

I know this question has some relation to work done by Richard Stanley, and I'm wondering if its actually a special case of the work of him, or someone else.

I'm kind of an abstract math noob so please ask clarifying questions if part of my question seems confusing. Also please go easy on me if this is actually a really easy problem, or related to a well known result.

Comment: Let $k,a_i$ be fixed, and $f(c)$ denotes the number of solution to $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i=c$. Then by inclusion-exclusion the number of solutions bounded by $x_i\leq d$ equals
$$\sum_{A\subseteq\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}} (-1)^{|A|} f\big(c-(d+1)\cdot\sum_{a\in A} a\big).$$

Comment: Can you explain please. It seems like this is using inclusion exclusion on d, but it seems like it uses f(c) in the answer since that is the term in the sum for the empty set.

Comment: Yes, $A$ can be the empty subset, which corresponds to term $f(c)$.

Comment: Oh I see thats the number of solutions to the unconstrained problem, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you happen to know the asymptotics of this function in terms of a_i's, d, k? Not the f function I know that one, but the inclusion exclusion sum you gave.

Comment: There is a lot known on this sort of thing.  You’re asking for the “atom probabilities” for a sort of Rademacher sum (see also “anticoncentration”).  It has to do with the additive structure of the coefficients $a_i$.  It gets into something called “inverse Littlewood-Offord theory” with folks like Terry Tao and Van Vu.